# Subsetting text based on matches between two vectors in R

Tags: r, arrays, subset

I have two vectors as follows in `R`:

```
A <- data.frame(c("Absolute Value", "absolute deviation", "acceptance line ; acceptance boundary", "age-adjusted rate", "variance", "modified mean ; modified arithmetic mean ; trimmed mean "))
B  <- data.frame(c("descriptive", "Acceptance Boundary", "deviation", "modified arithmetic mean", "mutability ; variability"))
```

I want to compare the two vectors and create a vector `C` with the terms of vector `B` that are not in the vector `A`. I want the code to ignore the capital letters, i.e. to recognise that `Acceptance Boundary` and `acceptance boundary` is the same and if the term appears in more than one way (;), e.g., `acceptance line ; acceptance boundary`, to recognise it as the same.

I want the final result to be:

```
C <- data.frame(c("descriptive", "deviation", "mutability ; variability"))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

First create vector `a` containing all (separate) expressions in `A` as an alternation pattern:

```
a <- A %>%
  # separate expressions into distinct rows:
  separate_rows(x, sep = " ; ") %>%
  # define the result as a vector:
  pull(x) %>%
  # connect the elements in the vector with alternation marker '|':
  str_c(., collapse = "|")
```

Then match the expressions in `a` to the (separate) expressions in `B`:

```
B %>%
  # separate the expressions into their own row each:
  separate_rows(x, sep = " ; ") %>%
  # match `x` to `a`& extract matches into new column:
  mutate(matches = str_extract_all(x, str_c("(?i)", a))) %>% 
  # unnest the listed items in the new column:
  unnest(where(is.list), keep_empty = TRUE) %>%
  # filter (i.e., retain only) the non-matches:
  filter(is.na(matches)) %>%
  # deselect the no-longer necessary column:
  select(-matches)
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  x          
  <chr>      
1 descriptive
2 deviation  
3 mutability 
4 variability
```

Data (note the use of `x` as column name):

```
A <- data.frame(x = c("Absolute Value", "absolute deviation", "acceptance line ; acceptance boundary", "age-adjusted rate", "variance", "modified mean ; modified arithmetic mean ; trimmed mean "))
B  <- data.frame(x = c("descriptive", "Acceptance Boundary", "deviation", "modified arithmetic mean", "mutability ; variability"))
```