# Subsetting text based on differences between two vectors in R

Tags: r, arrays, subset

I have two vectors with terms as follows in `R`:

```
A <- data.frame(c("Absolute Value", "absolute deviation", "acceptance line ; acceptance boundary", "age-adjusted rate", "variance", "modified mean ; modified arithmetic mean ; trimmed mean ", "standard error (stdev)"))
B  <- data.frame(c("descriptive", "Acceptance Boundary", "deviation", "stdev", "modified arithmetic mean", "mutability"))
```

I want to compare the two vectors and create a vector `C` with the terms of vector `B` that are not in the vector `A`. I want the code to ignore the capital letters, i.e. to recognise that `Acceptance Boundary` and `acceptance boundary` is the same and if the term appears in more than one way (;), e.g., (a) `acceptance line ; acceptance boundary`, or (b) `"standard error (stdev)"` and `"stdev"` to recognise it as the same.

I want the final result to be:

```
C <- data.frame(c("descriptive", "deviation", "mutability"))
```

In a similar question ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840776/subsetting-text-based-on-matches-between-two-vectors-in-r/74840996#74840996)), Chris provided a solution, however I couldn't adjust my code properly in order to make it work in this question's case.

Comment: hi nickolakis, welcome to stackoverflow. You will find a lot friends here, if you provide a reproducible example of what you have tried already or where the result of your attempt is not meeting your expectation. For the case at hand, you have vectors as part of your data frames A and B. The ` c(....)` is the unnamed vector. You provide a good problem statement. How did you check for `words` in your dataframe/vector B in A, how did you tackle the capital/non-capital problem? Have you read up on splitting strings and searching for certain letter combinations?

Comment: I just added some more information about a similar case in which i was based in order to make my code work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adapt the previous solution to the new data:

```
a <- A %>%
  # separate expressions into distinct rows:
  separate_rows(x, sep = " ; | \\(") %>%   # New
  # remove trailing ):                     # New
  mutate(x = str_remove(x, "\\)")) %>%     # New
  # define the result as a vector:
  pull(x) %>%
  # connect the elements in the vector with alternation marker '|':
  str_c(., collapse = "|")
```

Then match the expressions in `a` to the (separate) expressions in B:

```
B %>%
  # separate the expressions into their own row each:
  #separate_rows(x, sep = " ; ") %>%
  # match `x` to `a` & extract matches into new column:
  mutate(matches = str_extract_all(x, str_c("(?i)", a))) %>% 
  # unnest the listed items in the new column:
  unnest(where(is.list), keep_empty = TRUE) %>%
  # filter (i.e., retain only) the non-matches:
  filter(is.na(matches)) %>%
  # deselect the no-longer necessary column:
  select(-matches)
```

Comment: Thanks thats works perfectly. Just one more adjustment, in the `sep` of `a` can we add also the case where `;` and `()` exists in the same `""`?

Comment: That case is already taken care of by `" ; | \\("` , which splits **either** when there's a `;` **OR** when there's a `(`

Answer (score 1):

If `A` and `B` are vectors (not data frames as in your example), then you can use `strsplit()` and other helper functions like (`tolower()` and `trimws()`) to separate the values of `A` into separate words/concepts.  Then use `setdiff()` to find the differences between `B` and your cleaned set of words/concepts:

```
Avals = gsub("\\)", "", trimws(tolower(unlist(strsplit(A,"( ; )|( \\()")))))
setdiff(trimws(tolower(B)),Avals)
```

Output:

```
"descriptive" "deviation"   "mutability"
```

Input:

```
A = c("Absolute Value", "absolute deviation", "acceptance line ; acceptance boundary", 
"age-adjusted rate", "variance", "modified mean ; modified arithmetic mean ; trimmed mean ", 
"standard error (stdev)")

B = c("descriptive", "Acceptance Boundary", "deviation", "stdev", 
"modified arithmetic mean", "mutability")
```